# Check if new notifications are coming from any app

Tags: android, push-notification

Is it possible to check if there are new notifications available from your android device? I want to create something like pushbullet.

I want to give my app access to read all notifications of my device.

How do I do this? Can't figure it out.

Comment: do you mean this?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications()

Comment: Something like that, but I only need to execute my code if there is a new notification.

Comment: Something like onNewNotification(); like with GCM onMessage();

Comment: Check this listener maybe it helps
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html